# Difference Predictors in Auto.Arima Forecast

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm trying to build an auto.arima forecast with predictors like the example below.  I've noticed that my predictor is non-stationary.  So I was wondering if I should difference the predictor before inputting it in the xreg parameter, like I've shown below.  The real data set is much larger, this just an example.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
tsTrain <-tsTiTo[1:60]
tsTest <- tsTiTo[61:100]

ndiffs(ds$CustCount)
##returns 1

diffedCustCount<-diff(ds$CustCount,differences=1)

Xreg<-diffedCustCount[1:100]

##Predictor
xregTrain2 <- Xreg[1:60]
xregTest2 <- Xreg[61:100]


Arima.fit2 <- auto.arima(tsTrain, xreg = xregTrain2)

Acast2<-forecast(Arima.fit2, h=40, xreg = xregTest2)
```

Data:

```
dput(ds$CustCount[1:100])
```

c(3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 6, 8, 5, 2, 7, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 8, 7, 3, 5, 6, 6, 8, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, NA, NA, 4, 2, 2, 4, 11, 2, 8, 1, 4, 7, 11, 5, 3, 10, 7, 1, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 5, 9, 6, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 5, 8, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3, 1 )

```
dput(tsTiTo[1:100])
```

c(45, 34, 11, 79, 102, 45, 21, 45, 104, 20, 2, 207, 45, 2, 3, 153, 8, 2, 173, 11, 207, 79, 45, 153, 192, 173, 130, 4, 173, 174, 173, 130, 79, 154, 4, 104, 192, 153, 192, 104, 28, 173, 52, 45, 11, 29, 22, 81, 7, 79, 193, 104, 1, 1, 46, 130, 45, 154, 153, 7, 174, 21, 193, 45, 79, 173, 45, 153, 45, 173, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 79, 45, 79, 173, 45, 2, 173, 130, 104, 19, 4, 34, 2, 192, 42, 41, 31, 39, 11, 79, 4, 79)

Answer (score 2):

The `xreg` argument in `auto.arima` performs a `dynamic regression` which is to say that you are performing a linear regression and fitting the errors with an `arma` process.

While `auto.arima()` used to require manual differencing for non-stationary data when external regressors are included, this is no longer the case. `auto.arima()` will take non-stationary data as an input and determine the order of differencing using a unit-root test.

See this [Post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)  from Rob Hyndman for further detail.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've read the ARIMAX Model Muddle and Hyndman's textbook section on ARIMA and dynamic regression.  It's a little confusing, and I'm new to forecasting.  So just to make sure I'm clear on this, if I'm using auto.arima with xreg predictors and the time series I'm trying to forecast is stationary but the xreg predictors are non-stationary then I don't need to worry about manually differencing the predictors, auto.arima will test them and do it?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. With `auto.arima()` you don't need to worry about differencing your predictors or your forecasted variable.